# grep command not working inside the script for the search of string with spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix-timestamp

When I am running below command in unix terminal , its working fine

```
grep 'ND logistics' /Test/testdir
/asbced/some text/ND logistics Excel/new text
```

but when I am running same command inside a script, its not working

```
cat Test.txt
#!/bin/bash
filename = $1
echo "$filename"
grep "$filename" /Test/testdir >> test2.txt
```

Comment: `filename = $1` => `filename="$1"`. you cannot add space between `=`

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/2427222/ymonad. its working now